# Range of Electromagnetic Waves/Radio waves?

Tags: antenna, electromagnetism, energy

What basically determines that how far the electromagnetic waves will travel away from the source ? In our world where there is air and other materials how electromagnetic waves would generally response to them ? What will determine their range in our world. Especially radio waves are used all around us now a days. What determines their range ?

Comment: The first key factor is transmitter power output.

Comment: "What will determine their range in our world" - 1. transmitter power, 2. receiver sensitivity

Comment: @VicenteCunha - no, it really isn't, you can work the world on less than a watt.  In reality it is obstructions (especially buildings and terrain) vs. availability of reflectors.  Power level really only becomes an issue when you are competing with interference sources.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Agreed. But one must remember that even with no obstruction, free-space has path loss. What any engineer can "work with" end up being transmitter power and receiver sensitivity (most of the time). Other factors were mentioned by Andy.

Comment: Again, no.  Antennas and modulation scheme are generally the biggest wins.  Also receiver *selectivity* matters more than *sensitivity*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What basically determines that how far the electromagnetic waves will
>   travel away from the source ?

EM waves will travel to the edge of the universe.

> In our world where there is air and other materials how
>   electromagnetic waves would generally response to them ?

An EM wave will generally pass through air unhindered but some frequencies (such as 60 GHz) will be hindered by atmospheric absorption: -

[image]

> What will determine their range in our world.

Radio waves spread-out as they leave the source so the power thins out (just the same way as the perceived light from a distant lightbulb gets weaker). In order to be useful, the power received has to be greater than the background of thermal noise. A radio wave also has to be stronger (most of the time) than man-made interference. Lower frequencies are better because an antenna is bigger and naturally picks up a bigger signal (more power). The disadvantage is that longer wavelengths need much bigger antennas than smaller wavelengths.

- More transmit power = greater distance.
- Antenna directionality = more distance.
- Lower frequencies = bigger RX antenna = more RX power (or more distance).
- Some frequencies are better at penetration through objects than others.

Comment: Lower frequencies are typically used for long range terrestrial communication because they get bent/reflected back to Earth by the ionosphere.  The Voyager probes communicate in the 2ghz region.  New Horizons is up in the X-band (8-12ghz).

Comment: @CHendrix it's GHz not ghz

Comment: coffee didn't kick in yet...

Comment: Lower frequencies does not mean more distance.

Comment: @Chu yes, as a bullet point it's misleading but my words above the bullet point explained that lower frequencies means a bigger receive antenna which means more power at a given distance. I'll edit to make absolutely clear.

Comment: No, the antenna size argument is flawed.  If anything, you'll be better off with an antenna that is large compared to a wavelength, which means that lower frequencies require a larger antenna to achieve similar performance, at least down to wavelengths where manufacturing tolerances become a challenge.

Comment: @ChrisStratton the effective aperture for a simple antenna is proportional to \$\dfrac{\lambda^2}{4\pi}\$ - this is in square metres. Hence a bigger antenna will "collect" and convert more amps/m and volts/m (power/sq m) to power because it has larger effective area. This is fundamental in the Friis transmission equations. If you mean something else please do explain. See also this: http://www.antenna-theory.com/basics/friis.php

Comment: Again, you would do better designing that big antenna for a shorter wavelength where it will have more directivity.  Even better, take a look at how this is done in the real world - trying to guess from first principles without practical experience just gets you trapped in misconceptions.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I'm not designing an antenna for any wavelength I'm just reporting how it is to the OP with simple antennas. Can you leave an answer about getting more directivity from an antenna by making it bigger than a standard dipole. I'd certainly be interested in reading it because there isn't a whole lot lot of stuff on the net about it.

Comment: This is not a subject which can be adequately covered in an SO post - the asker would do better to read up on what is actually done in industry, or for a simpler take, the amateur service.  SO is intended to cover *specific problems* not substitute for general references.

Comment: Normal transmission lines around us also have electromagnetic waves. how much they travel in the surroundings of the transmission line ? @Andyaka

Comment: @Alex your original question covered a broad subject and now you want to move the goalposts to cover unintentional radiation from the plethora of transmission lines that use every frequency from 50 Hz to hundreds of MHz and can be wired in several different ways. Maybe consider asking a new question because it's answer should be independent of how it affects just intentional radio wave transmission.